# Ubuntu 17.10 freezing

Tags: intel-graphics, 17.10

I did a fresh 17.10 install, but it keeps freezing, I have used the c-state-idle tag in my grub config.
I had the same problem in 17.04 but got it fixed by installing the intel graphics update tool and intel firmwares.
So how do I solve issues on this one, given that intel has not released the update tool for 17.10 so far?
Also I'm running unity.

Thanks!